# VSCode removes my ts code. How to turn this off?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

It simply removes my code and I don't know how to turn it off. Any idea which setting I have to change.
Video: https://cloud.hilton.rwth-aachen.de/s/Tnwwcw4cYcJwwJC
This happens everywhere. Not only with imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by the [TypeScript Import Sorter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-co.import-sorter). Even when I disable `Sort before save` it applies the formatting instantly.